# Unable to post list of array with axious from vuejs to .net Core

Tags: .net, vue.js, asp.net-core, axios

i am working in vuejs with .net core as backend. When i post single array with axios it get posted but when i tried to post a list of array it is always 0 at server side when function get hit. Tried many ways but nothing helps.
here is my client side code.

```
let listOfRights=  [{ RouteName: "Rname", UserName: "Uname" }, { RouteName: "Rname1", UserName: "Uname1" }]
axios.request({
  method: 'POST',
          url: `/api/UserManager/saveUserRights`,
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
          },
          params:listOfRights,

        }).then(response => response.data).then(
          res => {
            debugger;
          });
```

and here is my server side code

```
        [Authorize]
        public IActionResult saveUserRights(List<MenuRights> listOfRights)
        {

            try
            {
                // further code
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }

            return Ok();
        }
```

but on server side it always gets 0 record.
When i post just one record for example on client side i change parameter from 
`params:listOfRights,`
 to 
`params:listOfRights[0],`
and on server side change from 
`public IActionResult saveUserRights(List<MenuRights> listOfRights)`
 to 
`public IActionResult saveUserRights(MenuRights listOfRights)`
then it gets posted.
but i want to post list. which is not getting posted. Thanks

[Image attached for first and second call and network posted tab as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLTHi.png)

Comment: Can you verify on your Chrome console, Network tab the network call and the corresponding data being passed to your API?

Comment: ```0: {"RouteName":"Rname1","UserName":"Uname1"}
1: {"RouteName":"Rname","UserName":"Uname"}```
this is getting passed to API

Comment: If this is getting passed, the next thing you need to do is to put a breakpoint on your server side code and verify whether the parameter `List<MenuRights> listOfRights` is actually getting the values passed by your Axios call.

Comment: i already added a breakpoint which gets hit but with empty list

Comment: Is there a method that gets hit prior to your controller being called? Maybe the data is being quashed at some point? Can you also post the code for the `MenuRights` class. Maybe some validation is deleting the data...

Comment: in class there are simple properties nothing else. and if data is getting erased at any point then why only on posting list. when i post a single array it gets posted.

Comment: Are you sure you are hitting the correct API controller method? Can you add a different controller with a post method, specify a direct `RoutePrefix("")` and `Route("")` attribute and see it it getting hit. Can you also post a screenshot of your Chrome Console network tab.

Comment: Image attached with question. 1st call is simple array and second is list. Posted on same API method. Network tab screenshot is also attached

Comment: On your screenshot (marked with 2), does listOfRights resolve to a list of `<vuejs.datamodels.SystemMenuRights>`? This is very intriguing given that your network call is showing you are passing the data, but on the server side code, it tells that you didn't. This can only lead me to conclusion that you are hitting something prior to your controller and what's happening is that the list is being cleared.

Comment: Fixed by adding [FromBody] tag in API method public IActionResult saveUserRights([FromBody]List<SystemMenuRights> listOfRights) and it is now accepting list as well.Thanks @Angelo for your help. It encourages me to think out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify the following codes:

```
let listOfRights= [
  { RouteName: "Rname", UserName: "Uname" }, 
  { RouteName: "Rname1", UserName: "Uname1" }
]


let url = '/api/UserManager/saveUserRights'

let headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}

axios.post(url, listOfRights, headers).then((response) => {
  console.log(response)
}, (error) => {
  console.log('EROR:', error)
})
```

And check the console.logs what it returns.

You can also put a breakpoint on your server side code to see if it does pass the correct data.

Comment: ```[{RouteName: "Rname", UserName: "Uname"}, {RouteName: "Rname1", UserName: "Uname1"}]
0: {RouteName: "Rname", UserName: "Uname"}
1: {RouteName: "Rname1", UserName: "Uname1"}
``` same nothing gets posted

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me. you can try this

```
      axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: '/api/customersfilter',
    data: {
      min_number: this.min_number,
      equal_num: this.equal_num,
      max_number: this.max_number,
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by adding [FromBody] tag in API method
`public IActionResult saveUserRights([FromBody]List<SystemMenuRights> listOfRights)`
and it is now accepting list as well.